# Looping through nested arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have an API that returns JSON data

Example JSON:

```
{
   "result":"OK",
   "data":[
      {
         "number":"613-555-5555",
         "calls":30
      },
      {
         "number":"613-666-5555",
         "calls":100
      }
   ]
}
```

I am trying to output this using javascript to show the following

> ```
> [number, calls],[number, calls]
> ```

```
var response = response.data;
var length = response.length;
alert(data[0].number);
alert(data[0].calls);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var arrayItem = data[i];
    document.write(arrayItem);
}
```

Comment: What output are you getting from what you currently have?

Comment: I should mention that the two alerts at the top work for getting the first position in the array.

Comment: I don't see nested arrays here.

Comment: You refer to `data` in one place, and `response` in the other. Which is it?

Comment: `console.log` is your friend.

Comment: @TravisJ `response` is the object you see up there. `data` is one of its properties.

Comment: `document.write` will overwrite the document on every iteration, so it's no suprise if this doesn't work ?

Comment: @Asad - Look again. `data` is not referenced and yet is said to exist. You cannot reference a property by simply using its name. By defining `var response = response.data;` does mean you can magically use `data` as a variable name.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: @Asad - More than likely this was meant: `var data = response.data;`, which is why I asked for clarification.

Comment: var data = response.data; response.data is the data from an ajax call.

Comment: So, again, what's your complete (minimal) code, and what's the current output?

Comment: @AndrewGoldenberg: Update your question to provide additional information instead of just posting it in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply a question of mapping your data to the desired format:

```
var final = response.data.map(function(item) {
    return [item.number, item.calls];
});
console.log(final);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c8UQg/

EDIT:

I didn't realise you were looking for a string representation (I thought you wanted an array). If that is the case, please disregard the above.

Comment: for the sake of clarity in code, I'd personally be a fan of seeing `function(data){ return [data.number, data.calls];}` simply because it's easier to read.

Comment: @ChaseFlorell `data` is being used to refer to a property of the original object, so I think using `data` to refer to the elements of `response.data` might be slightly confusing. I've tried to improve the naming nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

If you like everything the way it is code wise, and just want to fix the error, then I suggest changing

```
var response = response.data;
```

to

```
var data = response.data;
```

Also, for the sake of debugging, change

```
document.write(arrayItem);
```

to

```
console.log(arrayItem);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GptRW/

Comment: According to the comments, that's what OP is actually doing. The question states that the calls to `alert()` work, which means that the variable name in the original code is correct. The issue is therefore most likely the call to `document.write` after the page has loaded.

Comment: not a fan of answering questions based on comments. The entire question should be asked in the question. Also, trying to access `data[0]` when there is no  `data` object is going to be an issue beyond the `document.write` error.